# Class variable initialization in python

Tags: python, oop, static, static-variables

I have a class with a variable that should be an instance of this class. I can't create an instance at the declaration line because python interpreter does not know how to construct object at that moment. There is a possible workaround: initializing after the class declaration.

```
class A(object):
    static_variable = None

    def some_method(self, a=static_variable):
       print a

A.static_variable = A()
```

But I need to use that class variable as a default argument. It is possible to solve the problem this way:

```
def some_method(self, a=None):
    a = a if a else A.static_variable
    print a
```

However, it looks very nonpythonic to me. Any suggestion about how to use this kind of static variable as a default argument would be appreciated.

Comment: Using `param=None` then test for `if parem is None` is absolutely pythonic.

Comment: Why does the instance need to be a variable of the class at all? Why not simply define it at module level?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, I can define it at a module level, but still it does not solve the problem with the default parameter.

Comment: @MartijnPieters IMHO `def f(a=2): print a` is more pythonic compare to `def f(a=None): a = a if a 2; print a`

Comment: @midas: not when the default is a mutable and thus shared between all function calls.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, I did not mention default variable is immutable.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I included the variable into the class because it is kind of  unit element for A's instances

Comment: @midas: what I meant was that the pattern is *already often used* when the default value is immutable. It is also helpful here.

Comment: Your code has an indentation error (or syntax error). Is some_method a member of class 'A because it uses 'self'?

Comment: @Dan Yes, it does have an indentation problem. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Python does not support 'static' variables in the sense that languages like C++ do. So in this case, 'static_variable' is actually a class variable which is why you are encountering this problem. I'm sure you already know this, but others may stumble here someday and see us calling it a static variable so it seems like we should clear that up for posterity.

I was thinking that since 'static_variable' is still a member of class A, then maybe there was a way around by not using it as an argument at all.

Can you use a keyword argument in some_method()?

instead of using it as a default argument to the function, you could just call the variable 'A.static_variable' if the kwarg was not used.

```
class A(object):
    static_variable = None

    def some_method(self, *, a=None):
        if a:
            print(a)
        else:
            print(A.static_variable)

A.static_variable = A()
```